# Will Datastax solr supports Apache UIMA

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, uima

Does Datastax Solr support Apache UIMA? We are trying to build some text analysing using UIMA.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA

Above reference which allows opensource solr.

Comment: I don't know much about Datastax Solr, but worst case you can preprocess your documents with UIMA, and then store them (and the results from the text analytics) into Solr.